# Sublime Text 2 different indentations settings

Tags: sublimetext2, indentation

I want to configure my Sublime Text 2 to have two different types of indentations:

- 4 spaces for general use
- 2 spaces for my html pages

I think it should be done by editing the settings, but I don't know what to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key setting is `"tab_size"`. By default, if you look at **`Preferences -> Settings-Default`**, it is

```js
"tab_size": 4
```

The items in this file should absolutely not be modified. Instead, copy anything you want to change to the file opened by **`Preferences -> Settings-User`**, and alter the values there. It is saved as `Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings` where `Packages` is the folder opened by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**.

If you would like to have specific settings for certain syntaxes, open a new file in Sublime with JSON syntax. Like any other Sublime preferences file, open and close it with curly braces `{ }`. Put your desired settings in it, one per line, each followed by a comma `,` except the last entry (basically, it should be valid JSON, except JavaScript comments are also allowed).

```js
{
    "tab_size": 2,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

Finally, save it in your `Packages/User` folder as `Syntax Name.sublime-settings` - in your case, it should be `HTML.sublime-settings`. These settings should now be applied to any newly-opened or newly-created HTML files.

Comment: I found out a simpler way to do it "graphically". In **`Preferences -> Settings - More`**, there is an option callled **`Syntax Specific - User`** and it will lead to the same path just as you said